# "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 66

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have created a react-nativve app which perfectly run in Android devices but I have faced the `"xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 66` error when I run iOS app.

> nodeJS version: `v16.16.0`

> npm version: `8.11.0`

> pod version: `1.11.3`

After clone the github repo, I have install all of the dependencies using `npm i` command and then go to the **iOS** directory and install **iOS** dependencies uisng `pod install` command.

Then I would try to run the app in iOS using bellow command,

1. Start Metro: `npx react-native start`
2. Run iOS app: `npx react-native run-ios`

At the time to run iOS app I have faced `"xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 66` error which is given in attached file. Please check it and help me whc know about this.

Adavanced Thanks.

[image]